# How can I implement iLoggerFactory on my server IIS?

Tags: iis, logging, asp.net-core-2.1

I implement iLoggerFactory on my .Net Core API , step :

- creation of my folder 'logs'
- implementation of the log in my 'logs' folder ( in **startup.ts** )

  ```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
      // log implementation
      loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
      loggerFactory.AddDebug();
      loggerFactory.AddEventSourceLogger();
      loggerFactory.AddFile("logs/app-{Date}.txt");

      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseCors("AnyOrigin");
      app.UseSwagger();

      app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
      {
          c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebToolAPI");
          c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
      });
      app.UseMvc();
  }
  ```
- And I create some log in controller who look like this :

  ```
  _log.LogError("\r\n -- \r\n Datetime : {0} \r\n ERROR : id'" + id + "' not found \r\n --", DateTime.Now);
  ```

When I test it my local machine it's work but when I put my code in my IIS server it doesn't work. It doesn't create logs in my logs folder.

Comment: Could you please share the how you define the ILoggerFactory AddFile method? Which library you have used? or you build a custom ILoggerFactory? If you could post more details information, it will be more easily for us to reproduce the issue and find out the solution.

Comment: Hi, I have someone who help me I will post the solution for those who have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue.

In **Startup.cs** :

```
public class Startup
{
    string LogFilePath;
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // location of the logs
        var exePath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.ToString();
        var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
        LogFilePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath + "\\logs\\"); // you can replace "logs" by an other folder name
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        loggerFactory.AddFile(LogFilePath + "api-{Date}.txt",LogLevel.Debug,null,false,null,30); // you can replace "api" by an other file name for your log
    }
}
```

In **Program.cs** :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```